# How to use multiple HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS and get results in all the indexes using drf-haystack management commands?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, drf-haystack

I can use only one connection at a time during rebuild_index manage command. I need these two results simultaneously.

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['services.search_indexes.ViewServiceIndex'],
},
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
# To use default connection
sqs = SearchQuerySet().using('default')
# To use new connection
sqs = SearchQuerySet().using('new')
```

A normal rebuild-index will work. The way to use different connections are:

1. List item
2. I have named both of them default, change one of them to something different, say "new".
3. The INDEX_NAME must also be changed.
4. Use the above code to access the data.